# Is it possible to send visitors to your website's host without changing your nameservers?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, cname, nameservers, mx-record

I have a domain name registered with Enom and I have all my MX records, TXT records and some CNAME set up there and working great.

My dilemma is that I hired someone to build a (Wordpress) site for me and host it by them. They want me to change the nameservers to point to their domain.

That would mean that they technically would have control over my domain records which I would prefer not be the case. Also, everything is working well the way it is on the current nameservers and I'd prefer not to change it.

**Is there any way to send my website visitors to my new website at its new host without changing my name servers?**

Answer (score 0):

Ask your developer for the new website IP address location (e.g 190.200.194.1).

Under your DNS settings at Enom - change the "A" Record with your domain name entry to the new IP address.

Changes will appear once propagation is complete.

Hope this helps

Comment: will that cause issues with Wordpress?